# flutter text in tablerow got squash

Tags: flutter, text, styles, line, tablerow

i wonder why my text sometimes looks squash, here is a photo of why it looks like this [image]

especially the status : unassigned, the data are all fetch from firebase and display in table form

can i know what is going on? i dont know what causes it and dont know how to fix it, i need some guidance, thanks in advance

here is my table code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp/appointment/AppointmentDetails.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../extensions.dart';
import 'createFunction/selectService.dart';
bool loggedIn = true;
bool notLoggedIn = true;
String answer = '';
class appointmentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const appointmentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<appointmentPage> createState() => _appointmentPageState();
}

class _appointmentPageState extends State<appointmentPage> {
  @override

  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String searchText = '';
  String dropdownvalue = 'View All';
  void dispose() {
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    loadPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadPref() async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      answer = (pref.getString('adminEmail')).toString();
      if(answer == ''){
        loggedIn = false;
        notLoggedIn = true;
      }else if(answer != ''){
        loggedIn = true;
        notLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });
    }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var items = [
      'View All',
      'View Unpaid',
      'View Paid',
      'View Unassigned',
      'View Completed',
      'View Cancelled',
      'View Assigned'
    ];

    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment');
    // Query<Map<String, dynamic>> allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('payStatus', isEqualTo: dropdownvalue);
    if(dropdownvalue == 'View All'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment');
    } else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Unpaid'){
       allNoteCollection= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('payStatus', isEqualTo: 'Pay later at store');
    }else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Paid'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('payStatus', isEqualTo: 'Paid');
    }else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Assigned'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('status', isEqualTo: 'assigned');
    }else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Completed'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('status', isEqualTo: 'completed');
    }else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Unassigned'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('status', isEqualTo: 'unassigned');
    }else if(dropdownvalue == 'View Cancelled'){
      allNoteCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Appointment').where('status', isEqualTo: 'cancelled');
    }

    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = [];
    if(answer != ''){
      notLoggedIn = false;
      loggedIn = true;
      setState(() {});
    }else if(answer == ''){
      loggedIn = false;
      notLoggedIn = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Appointment Page'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Visibility(
              visible: notLoggedIn,child:
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 180,
              width: 280,
              child: Card(
                color: '03045E'.toColor(),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Center(child: Text('There is no assigned', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),)),
                      Center(child: Text('assignment', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),)),
                      SizedBox(height:20,),
                      Center(child: Text('All assignments are either', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),)),
                      Center(child: Text('completed or unassigned', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          ),

          TextField(
            controller: searchController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                searchText = value;
              });
            },
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search...',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: loggedIn,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 52,),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Card(
                        color: '2196f3'.toColor(),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          dropdownColor: '2196f3'.toColor(),
                            isExpanded: true,
                            value: dropdownvalue,
                            items: items.map((String items){
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: items,
                                  child: Center(child: Text(items, style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white ), )));
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (String? newValue){
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Visibility(
            visible: loggedIn,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,100,0,0),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: allNoteCollection.snapshots(),
                        builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
                      if (streamSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      documents = streamSnapshot.data!.docs;
                      if (searchText.isNotEmpty) {
                        documents = documents.where((element) {
                          return (element
                                  .get('carPlate')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                              element
                                  .get('custName')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                              element
                                  .get('date')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                              element
                                  .get('timeEnd')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                              element
                                  .get('timeStart')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                              element
                                  .get('serviceName')
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()));
                        }).toList();
                      }
                      return ListView.separated(
                        reverse: true,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: documents.length,
                        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return const Divider();
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          String newTimeEnd = '';
                          int countStart = int.parse(documents[index]['timeStart']);
                          int countEnd = int.parse(documents[index]['timeEnd']);
                          int finalCount = countEnd - countStart;
                          if(finalCount > 1){
                            int timeEnding = int.parse(documents[index]['timeEnd']) + 1;
                            newTimeEnd = timeEnding.toString();
                          }else{
                            int timeEnding = int.parse(documents[index]['timeEnd']) + 0;
                            newTimeEnd = timeEnding.toString();
                          }
                          return ListTile(
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => AppointmentDetails(
                                              id: documents[index]['id'],
                                              custName: documents[index]
                                                  ['custName'],
                                              carPlate: documents[index]
                                                  ['carPlate'],
                                            )));
                              },
                              title:
                              Table(
                                children: [
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 5,), SizedBox(height: 5,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Date', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['date']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Car Plate', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['carPlate']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Service', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['serviceName']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Price', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['payment']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Customer', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['custName']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Pay Status', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['payStatus']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Status', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['status']}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Time Start', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${documents[index]['timeStart']}:00 Hour', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                  const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 8,), SizedBox(height: 8,)]),
                                  TableRow(
                                      children: [
                                        const Center(child: Text('Time End', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                        Text(': ${newTimeEnd}:00 Hour', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              trailing: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                content: const Text(
                                                    'Are you sure you want to remove this appointment?'),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    // FlatButton widget is used to make a text to work like a button
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                                  ),
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      db.collection("Appointment").doc(documents[index]
                                                                  ['id'].toString()).delete().then((doc) => print(
                                                                "Document deleted"),
                                                            onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"),
                                                          );
                                                      final remove =
                                                          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
                                                                  'Assignment').doc(documents[index]['id']);
                                                      remove.update({
                                                        'status': 'cancelled'
                                                      });
                                                      resetTimeSlot(documents[index]['timeStart'],
                                                          documents[index]['date'],
                                                          documents[index]['hoursNeed']);
                                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                    },
                                                    child: const Text('Delete'),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            });
                                      },
                                      child: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
                                ],
                              ));
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 70,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: loggedIn,
            child: Positioned(
              bottom: 15,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 45,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => selectService()));
                      },
                      child: const Text('Create Appointment', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 18),),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: where do you use this table?

Comment: sorry i miss out the message, i have updated the code, i wonder why some of the text got like squash, can i kno why ?

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` by default has specific size for its `title` and that is why your `table` squash. so you need to change `visualDensity` like this:

```
ListTile(
   visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 2),
   ....
),
```

Comment: you can also set it 3 or 4 to get what is good for you. @Lim

Comment: @Lim was it what you want?